# Angular ui-router state is not redirecting or changing the url

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code which I would like to redirect to another page once the call to a service is successfully finished.

```
        bsn.create = function () {
            BusinessService.create(bsn.business).then(function (
                $state.go('student.home',{});
            }).catch(function (error) {
                $rootScope.result = error;
            });
        };
```

For some reason this is not redirecting the view. So i do call this on ng-click button and I do have 'student.home' defined on the route states.

I also inject '$state' param on the controller but still no working.

It is not showing any error at all, any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you just try to modify this `$state.go('student.home',{});` with `$state.go('student.home');`

Comment: @KunalKakkad I did and nothing changed...

Comment: can you post your routes here?

Comment: can you please share the routing configuration code..

Comment: @war1oc .state('student.home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'views/student/home.html',
                resolve: {}

Comment: I did found out the issue and fixed. sorry I was in the same route and trying to reload at the same url.. I did used this $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}) to refresh the view. thnx and sorry, it was my bad...

Comment: its ok, good to know it worked out